# Oracle efficient way of updating non-indexed and non-partioned table?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Is there an efficient way to update rows of a table that has no indexes and no partitions (and ~50millions rows)?

I have a date field LOAD_DTTM and values of this field for rows that require update (around 2000 distinct dates).

WIll update be faster if i specify a date in a WHERE clause along with the UNIQUE_ID of a row?

Comment: No, you are doomed to scan the entire table looking for the rows you need to update.  That's why indexes were invented!

Comment: @Mari . . . Your question is unclear.  Do you need to update all rows?  Or just a small number?

Comment: I have rebuilt that table, created indexes and partitions. This was the best option, thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update all, or a large number, of the rows then the quickest way is:

```
create table my_table_copy as
select ... -- all the columns, updating values as required
from my_table;

drop table my_table;

rename my_table_copy to my_table;
```

If your table had any indexes, constraints or triggers you would now need to re-add them - but it seems you don't have that issue!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a PL/SQL procedure that loops and update and commit the table every n row count -- Say every 20.000 rows. I do not advise to update the full table as it will create a lock for a looong time and expose you to data loss in case of external factors.

Comment: what you describe will be a performance killer, and with the commits inside a loop, will be very susceptible to ora-1555.  Processing 'row-by-row' means processing 'slow-by-slow'.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**. 
Even if you specify both conditions in your WHERE clause as you stated, it won't help you to avoid a full scan of your table. 
Even if one of your criteria will uniquely identify the row, it still won't help.

There is a real example tested on Oracle 12C ver.2 similar to your case. No indexes, no partitions, nothing. Just plain table with 4 columns

I have a table with 18mn records. 
I also have CUSTOMER_ID which is a UNIQUE identifier for a row. 
I also have ORDER_DATE column there.

Even if I do the query that you mentioned

```
update hit set status = 1 where customer_id = 408518625844 and order_date = '09-DEC-19';
```

it won't help me to avoid a full table scan. See below Execution Plan. Therefore under conditions, you've specified, you will be always getting the slowest execution time possible. Full Table Scan on 50mn rows is actually the worst-case scenario.

[image]

And pay attention to that Cost, it is 26539 on 18mn rows. 
So if you have 50mn rows we can easily expect much more Cost for your query